# cannot add to database mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am having trouble with my form adding to my database.

I have made the form and the script but am having trouble implementing them. Any ideas?

Table:

[image: Image of table]

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form method="post" id="form2" action="home.php?id=<?php echo "$user_id";?>">  </br>
    <h2>What would you like to ask? Rant away!</h2>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Write a title" size="92px"/>
    <textarea cols= "70px" rows="6px" name="content";>Description...</textarea><br/>
    <select name="topic">
        <option> Select Topic</option>
        <?php getTopics() ;?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name ="submitbtn" value="Post to Timeline"/>
</form>

<?php 
    insert_post();?>
```

Here is the function - the file the function is in, is included in the HTML file using the include command at the top of the file.

```
function insert_post(){
    if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
        global $con;
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $content=$_POST['content'];
        $topic=$_POST['topic'];

        $insert="INSERT INTO `posts` ( `user_id`, `topic_id`, `post_title`, `post_content`, `post_date`) 
        VALUES ('$user_id','$topic','$title','$content',NOW()) ";

        $run=mysqli_query($con, $insert);
        if($run){
            echo"<h3>Discussion posted</h3>";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
For reference, the error I get when clicking the submit is a 404 which says "object not found".

EDIT 2: 
Image of table shows the row is called `pos_title` whereas my own code says `post_title`. When code was edited to say `pos_title`, the same error still arose.

EDIT 3:
New errors after implementing some suggested changes:

[image: New errors]

Comment: can you show us the table

Comment: then that should mean that home.php must not exist

Comment: The first thing I would look into is why `$con` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){` from the functions and add this above the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
    insert_post();
}
```

Comment: That has successfully allowed me to add a blank entry to the database, which is significantly further than I've gotten so far, so cheers for advice here. 
However now the values are all undefined:
' Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\includes\functions.php on line 30 '
there is one of these for each of the VALUES as well as somehow with the $con later on. I will add an image of the errors to the original post

Comment: where is $user_id defined at?

Comment: $user-_id is from the values going in to the table. So it is from the table 'posts'.       

it also seems to have led to an endless transfer of data to the host, the page home.php is now constantly loading

Comment: try adding the code in the function and put it in the place of insert_post();

Comment: I have emailed you the file. The constant load issue was my fault also, the back and forth copy pasting i had accidentally called the function inside itself which was causing that.

Comment: The issue is definitely with the form itself and likely not the function as when I am logged in with separate users, those blank submissions return the correct user_ID. So the variables for topic, content and title must just be empty somehow.

EDIT: In fact, they are empty because the submission button is likely not working?

Comment: Try echoing something if the form is submited

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert="INSERT INTO `posts` ( `user_id`, `topic_id`, `post_title`, `post_content`, `post_date`) 
    VALUES ('" . $user_id . "','" . $topic . "','" . $title . "','" . $content . "',NOW()) ";
```

Try this code. You should concatenate using the `.` instead of inserting variables in the string:

```
$run=mysqli_query($con, $insert);
if($run) {
    echo"<h3>Discussion posted</h3>";
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

NOTE:
also for debugging purposes you should check `mysqli_error($con);` if there's an error.

```
<form method="post" id="form2" action="home.php?id=<?php echo $user_id;?>">  </br>
```

When you echo a variable there is no need for double quotes. It is a variable not a string.

```
    <textarea cols= "70px" rows="6px" name="content">Description...</textarea><br/>
```

And you have a semicolon after `name="content"` that should not be there as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks for help, however I am afraid it didn't solve my problem. I have edited the code above to more specifically explain the error i get after clicking the button.
When submit is clicked it is a 404.
I have also included your debugging code, thanks for advice on that.
I get same error with both mine and your code.

Comment: are you sure home.php exits?? @Davidf

Comment: Yes, the form in question is placed in home.php which already has used user_id earlier in the file
the function is from functions.php which i included with : 
include ("functions.php");
They are in the same directory also

Comment: try removing it out of the funtion and try it @Davidf

Comment: Do you mean remove home.php from the function? 
same error when I tried that

Comment: no take out the if statement for if(isset($_POST['submitform'])) from in the function

Comment: ok is this function in the home.php file? and can you show me how its being called

Comment: the function resides in a file called functions.php which is included at the beginning of the file
I have edited the code to include the calling of the function which happens straight after form

Comment: try echoing the results of the variables and see what is returned

Comment: returns an error "Notice: Undefined variable: topic in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\home.php on line 117"

However this may be because it is not filled until submission anyway as it is an if statement activated when the submission is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change action to `action="home.php"`.
2. Add this code to form:

   ```
   <input value="<?php echo $user_id?>" type="hidden" name="user_id">
   ```
3. Add this code to `insert_post` function:

   ```
   $user_id = (int)$_POST['user_id'];
   ```
4. Replace  `post_title` to  `pos_title` or alter your table.
5. You don't need the quotes in `'$user_id'`, `'$topic'`, but MySQL will still accept it.

Comment: still throws same 404 error. no data added to table

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you all for your time and effort and help. It turned out there had been a syntax error about 400 lines higher than this form at the previous form, where I'd typo'd when closing it. So the question I had asked was unsolvable for you as it turns out the code shared was more or less fine. So very big apologies for my mistake guys and thanks so much for all your help. This has certainly taught me to clean up my html files and not let them get so big!